# ¿Comó convertir string a jsonObject?

Tags: java, android, gson

Necesito realizar lo siguiente convertir un string a JSONOBJECT en android java. Tengo una variable de tipo string como

```
String userobj = "{name:" + name +",email:" + email +",id:"+id + ",photo:" + photo + "}";
```

Y lo necesito convertir a tipo JSONOBJECT. Ya he probado de la siguiente manera

```
new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(userobj))
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error

> type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Hay alguna manera en que esto se pueda realizar y logre obtener un objeto json del tipo:

```
   "name":"avatar",
   "email":"test1@gmail.com",
   "id":"445345646",
   "photo":"sn"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) SUGERENCIA:** Yo personalmente crearía el `JsonObject` directamente de la siguiente manera.

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    jsonObject.addProperty("name", name);
    jsonObject.addProperty("email", email);
    jsonObject.addProperty("id", id);
    jsonObject.addProperty("photo", photo);
```

Al hacer un Log de esta variable da como resultado

```
I/MLog: json jsonObject -> {"name":"Leonardo","email":"@lhenaoll","id":1,"photo":"picture"}
```

**2) SOLUCION:** Pero si lo que realmente necesitas hacer realmente es convertir un String que regrese algún servidor a JSON la manera de hacerlo es pasando directamente el String a la variable que contiene el `new JsonObject()` y encerrar este proceso en un `try-catch` para evitar rupturas.

```
    String userobj = "{name:" + name + ",email:" + email + ",id:" + id + ",photo:" + photo + "}";
    JSONObject json_transform = null;
    try {

        json_transform = new JSONObject(userobj);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Al hacer el Log de esta variable da como resultado

```
I/MLog: json transform -> {"name":"Leonardo","email":"@lhenaoll","id":1,"photo":"picture"}
```